# How to Read XML into a DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid

I have a class that goes to a URL and gets a xml document using xmlDoc.Load(URL).  To test the class, I added a web project to display the xml in a grid view.

In a button click I create an instance of an xml document and populate it as:

xmlDoc = myClassName()

I'm stuck at how to get xmlDoc into a format usable by the datasource

I am totally confused as to how to get the xml to be displayed in the grid as dataset.ReadXml seems to want a file path.  I don't understand the other overloads.  I suppose I have to read the xml into a string or something else, but I don't understand how to do this - even after reading numerous posts here and MSDN  - Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example:

```
string xml =@"<xml><customer><id>1</id></customer></xml>";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Now set the datasource to your grid:

```
grid.DataSource=newDataSet.Tables[0];
```

**Update:**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
//xmlDocument is your XmlDocument instance
ds.ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlDocument.InnerXml)));

grid.DataSource=newDataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: The class returns an instance of System.Xml.XmlDocument.  It is not a string.

Comment: XmlTextReader also expects a file path which I do't have as it is not stored on disk.

Comment: @Brian I am not using XmlTextReader at all. I don't know what are your referring to...

Comment: thanks - I'll give it a whirl... last comment was posted just before your update

Comment: @Brian .InnerXml is just a method that returns the string xml representation of the XmlDocument object. Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml.aspx

Comment: OK must be something wrong with my xml - top line as returned in a browser is <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>

Comment: That's normal. I just ran a test inserting the line you pasted at the top of my xml string and it worked just fine.

Comment: Well, You have answered my question - I'll figure out my isue.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to clean up and wrap the readers in a using statement.