# Read dynamically created xml document to dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, dataset

I have to read a dynamically created xml documnet to a dataset.But don't know how to achieve that.I wrote some code as below.

```
    private void ConvertXMLToDT(string myXML)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocs = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocs.LoadXml(myXML);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlDocs);   //--->this statement doesn't work
        DataTable dtFormats = ds.Tables[0];
        DataTable dtPreset1 = ds.Tables[1];        
        Response.Write("done");
    }
```

Is there any possible way to do that.

Comment: their is not parameter type of XmlDocument in DataSet.ReadXml method. it support "filename(string), IO.Stream, TextReader, XmlReader" types.

Comment: is there any possible way to get that xml in the dataset in this context

Comment: Hopefull, this link will help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536637/how-to-read-xml-into-a-dataset

Comment: @Arvin this link is also [help you] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047064/convert-string-to-system-io-stream)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kumar Manish. It helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

I have modified my code as per the comments above in the questions and working fine now

```
private void ConvertXMLToDT(string myXML)
{
    //XmlDocument xmlDocs = new XmlDocument();
    //xmlDocs.LoadXml(myXML);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //ds.ReadXml(xmlDocs);   //--->this statement doesn't work
    ds.ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(myXML)));
    DataTable dtFormats = ds.Tables[0];
    DataTable dtPreset1 = ds.Tables[1];        
    Response.Write("done");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may help for you:

```
 public DataTable ConvertXMLToDT(string xml)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)));
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```